# Keep on getting "error: package console does not exist"

Tags: android

So I'm working on this simple program, and I keep getting this error and it says `error: package console does not exist
    console.out.println("My name is " + myName);`

I'm wondering how to fix that. I'm really new to this whole Java thing and if any of you guys could explain it like I'm 5 that would be great. Here's my code. ---> pastebin.com/k3nqWspr

Comment: You could try `System.out.println()`, assuming this would pipe out to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System class has standard streams. There is no standard *console* class. System.out is a standard output stream.